Drive up to 64 coils (one at a time)
I want to drive up to 64 (PCB) coils at 5V / 200mA using a PWM signal from a micro controller. I only need to control one coil at a time. So I have two questions:

How can I multiplex the PWM signal?
Are some 74HC595 Shift Registers a good solution or are there simpler / cheaper options?

How do I drive the coils?
Do I need a driver (e.g. a N-channel MOSFET and a flyback diode) per coil or is there a clever design to reduce complexity and lower the cost?



what is a "coil", and how much current does it use?  In fact, if you show some sort of a circuit diagram for driving one coil, it would be a big help.

Are the coils energized randomly (any coils in any order) or sequentially (always in the same order)?

@AnalogKid they are energized randomly, although the next one will always be a neighbour in the 8x8 grid

What limits the current? Do these coils have 25 ohms internal resistance and thus draw 200mA on their own when powered from 5V, or does this require further measures like active current control if the internal resistance is much lower?

@bobflux They have an internal resistance of 25 ohms and don't need current control

how fast do you need to switch?

If you try to multiplex the coils in an 8 x 8 array you will need a series diode and a flyback diode per coil. That's already 128 parts before the drivers.
You might consider the TPIC series of DMOS power shift registers from TI. The have internal clamping which allows the coils to switch more quickly, at the expense of whacking the internal MOSFETs a bit hard. It looks like they'd be okay with 200mA on a single output continuously up to about 62°C case temperature so they might need a small heat sink. Also pay attention to the maximum clamping energy. PCB coils are usually pretty low inductance so you may be okay on that account.
This more expensive model can easily handle the current.
In any case, if this works for you, it would be only 8 components total (plus the all-important supply bypass capacitors).
Layout is really important when you mix signals with fast-switching power outputs. I would suggest a 4-layer board if you go this way. Trying to use a solderless breadboard would likely end in tears. That is one point in favour of using separate logic and drivers, as might be parts cost (many, many cheaper parts).

Thank you for your detailed answer. If I understand correctly, you suggest that using a driver per coil might be easier and cheaper than power shift registers?

If you use a driver per coil you'd still need the shift registers (or equivalent) but you'd need 64 switches and 64 diodes. If you could stand the loss of a Darlington, then 8 74HC595 + 8 ULN2803 (and nothing else save some bypass caps) would likely be a good cheap/simple way to go. Possibly cheapest. t might even be a good way if you had to boost the 5V to something higher with a few components. You might also want to think about the layout too- if it's linear or more chessboardesque.

Current total price from LCSC is about $1.30 for those 16 parts.

You should be able to do it with an 8 x 8 matrix, 8 low side switches, 8 high side switches in a row/column arrangement. This way you only need 16 outputs and 16 switching transistors.
Then for whichever coil you want to energize you turn on the two transistors for it's row and column. For PWM you could drive either the rows or columns with the PWM signal.
Here's a 3 x 3 matrix, to activate coil 8 you would turn on the drivers for Row 3 and Column 2.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

With two, 3-line-to-8-line decoders, only 6 output bits for 63 coils, and 7 bits for 64 coils.

@AnalogKid Yes, you can of course use  decoders or shift registers to reduce the number of outputs needed.

With only 5 V to work with, I assume that getting the max voltage across a coil is important.  This rules out most driver arrays such as the ubiquitous ULN2803.  The stages are darlington transistors, so there is a voltage drop across an "on" output of around 0.8 V.  Worse, integrated pull-up arrays use emitter-follower outputs for an even larger "on" voltage.
If you don't want to deal with 16 individual transistors, a compromise is a quad array.  The 2N3904 and 3906 are available in 14-pin packages, 4 transistors in each.  A compromise would be one ULN2803 for the sinks, and two 2N3906 arrays for the sources.

Using individual shift register outputs to drive each single coil(-driver, if using a separate one) does not mean you need to bang out (up to) 64 bits:
Data inputs of "the LED shift registers" connected together, use one more (master?) shift register's output to control control signal(s).
This should limit the number of bits to 16.
'595 not having clock enables, output enable looks viable.


(Freewheel diodes are omitted)
In this example with 4 coils, the intended current path is in blue (X1 and X4 are ON) but there is also an unintended current path in red. If you use a Matrix configuration, this will always occur unless you use one diode per coil to block unintended paths. Thus you need one blocking diode and one freewheel diode per coil, that's already 128 components.
In a "dumb" configuration where you would drive each coil with its own MOSFET, you would also need one MOSFET and one freewheel diode per coil, so the number of components is the same.
Whether you use a service like JLCPCB to assemble the board or hand solder, per-part cost is an important factor. Diodes are cheaper than MOSFETs, but once you factor in the assembly cost, if you can find cheap MOSFETs... meh.
MOSFETs can also be replaced with power shift registers like TPIC6C595 or 596 (also available as STPIC, NPIC, etc from other manufacturers). This is not necessarily cheaper than individual MOSFETs plus shift registers. Freewheeling diodes are not included in the chip.
Without a freewheel diode, the internal MOSFET absorbs the coil's stored energy by avalanche at switch off, which is useful as it dissipates inductor current much quicker than a diode. But inductor stored energy will turn into heat in the MOSFET at each turn off, so depending on your inductance and PWM frequency, the internal MOSFET may overheat from repeated avalanche. Also you will not get a smooth current in the coil, due to the fast turnoff from the avalanching MOSFET. So whether you use freewheel diodes or not should be decided on the desired current shape in the coils, and temperature of the chips.
Using these chips, I found them to be a bit flaky. There's no problem when switching relay coils, but when the relay drove a particularly nasty motorized valve with a limit switch, I noticed the switch bouncing sent enough EMI through the relay and into the chip to reset it. That's a potential problem: the shift register, which contains the memory of the current state... is on the same chip as the power switch which gets all the noise thrown at it.
So a separate solution with 74HC595 and discrete FETs should have better immunity. Whether it will matter in your designs, I cannot say.
Personally I would use one FET per coil, driven either by HC595 or a 6 bit to 64 outputs decoder built out of 3-to-8 decoders. The former option is more flexible since you can power more than one coil at the same time. The latter has no memory, it is simple combinatorial logic, so it can't be reset and has best noise immunity.
